# outside variable not available inside enhanced for

Tags: java

could anyone find why i am getting the error in the following code:

```
public class EnhancedFor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int i;
        int[] test = new int[10];

        for(i:test)
            System.out.print(i+" ");
    }

}
```

Comment: Huh. I'd never actually tried using a for-each without declaring the iteration variable in the parentheses. I've never seen anything explicitly saying you need to do that, but apparently you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we write a `for` loop in it's enhanced form to iterate over a container(i.e., an array or collection), we generally always iterate from the beginning to the end.  This statement has the form:

```
for ( Type VariableDeclaratorId : Expression ) 
            Statement
```

The type `Type` of the Expression must be defined and as a `Iterable` or an array type or a compile-time error occurs. The reason that we must declare a new variable id with specific type in enhanced-for loop statement is that, it limits the scope of the variable id within the loop body providing more [clarity and safety](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html).

According to **[the java language specification: 14.14.2 The enhanced for statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2)**

> The enhanced for statement is equivalent to a basic for statement of
>   the form:

```
for (I #i = Expression.iterator(); #i.hasNext(); ) {
    VariableModifiers_opt
 TargetType Identifier =
        (TargetType) #i.next();
    Statement
}
```

> **`#i`  is  an  *automatically*  generated  identifier  that  is  *distinct*  from  any  other identifiers (automatically generated or otherwise) that are in scope (§6.3) at the point where the enhanced-for statement occurs.**

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
int[] test = new int[10];
for(int i : test)
    System.out.print(i + " ");
```

For the more information, see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)

Comment: does this mean that none of the variables declared in the main method are not available in enhanced for or is it like restriction is only the index in the loop

Comment: You could use variables declared in the main method *in* your for-each loop.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because that's not syntactically correct. The enhanced for-loop looks like this:

```
for(int i : test) {
  System.out.println(Integer.toString(i));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] test = new int[10];

    for(int i :test)
        System.out.print(i+" ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the variable inside the enhanced for statement:

`for(int i : test)`